# Store dont load in renderer grid cell

Tags: extjs, grid, store, renderer

I´m trying to renderer a string in my column instead of your id. I founded this solution: [Grid cell is rendering wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992450/grid-cell-is-rendering-wrong), but it´s don´t work with a dynamic store.

In my grid I put a store to load into the renderer:

```
columns: [
                  {xtype : 'gridcolumn', text: 'Id', dataIndex: 'id'},
                  {xtype : 'gridcolumn', text: 'Validade', dataIndex: 'dataValidade', renderer: function(object){return Ext.Date.format(object, 'd-m-Y');}},
                  {xtype : 'gridcolumn', text: 'Complexo', dataIndex: 'id', renderer: function(value) {
                        storeComplexoPorValidade.getProxy().url = caminhoContexto + "validade/complexoporid/" + value + "/dados.json";
                        storeComplexoPorValidade.load();
                        console.log(storeComplexoPorValidade);
                        var idx = storeComplexoPorValidade.find('id', value);
                        var rec = storeComplexoPorValidade.getAt(idx);
                        return rec.get('descricao');  
                        }
                  },
```

But the store don´t load the data to var, although perform the request. And I catch the error: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined.

What´s wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I have a lot work to make my script work. And with your tips I founded two others solutions that help me to put my code working. [How to wait until all stores are loaded in ExtJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003605/how-to-wait-until-all-stores-are-loaded-in-extjs) and http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?197265-Loading-stores-synchronously

It´s my code working:

```
Ext.define('validade', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [{name: 'id', type: 'int'},
         {name: 'dataValidade', type: 'date', dateFormat:'Y-m-d'},
         {name: 'complexo', type: 'string', persist: 'false' }]
```

});

```
Ext.define('ValidadeStore',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'validade',
pageSize: itemsPerPage,
remoteSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property : 'id',
        direction: 'DESC'
    }],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url : '/validade/grid/dados.json',
    reader : {
        type : 'json',
        root : 'data'
    },
},
autoLoad: {
    callback: function(records, operation, success){
        var i = 0

        loadComplexo();

        function loadComplexo(){
            if (i < records.length) {
                var rec = records[i];
                i++;
                storeComplexo.getProxy().url = "validade/complexoporid/" + rec.get('id') + "/dados.json";
                storeComplexo.load({
                    callback: function(records, operation, success){
                        var rec_ = records[0];
                        rec.set('complexo',rec_.get('descricao'));
                        loadComplexo();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because the store load is asynch, so the "return" from the **renderer** will complete before the response of your proxy request is received, processed, and made available to even be assigned to the variable you're trying to set.

I would suggest that you rethink your approach here. A couple options:

1. Load the store you're trying to use for the custom rendering prior to the creation of the grid
2. Expand your underlying data model for the grid's store with the extra fields that you need to perform the custom rendering. You can always mark these extra fields as non-persistent, so they will not be included in any write actions that might be performed on the model instance.

Comment: How I can to load before? I´m trying here, but don´t work yet. My principal store load into the initComponent in my Ext.window.Window, and don´t load the data to var too. But, when I call the function in 'itemclick' listener, it´s work.

Comment: So before you create the window, you could run the load action for the helper store. In this store's callback, you could do your window creation there so that you'll know that the helper store is loaded and ready to go. Then, you could simply get a reference to the store within your columns renderer, and look up the values as you're doing, without the proxy load.

Comment: If the helper store contains static data (e.g., some lookup values from a database table that doesn't, or rarely, changes), you could always load the data on the startup of your app. That way you'd always have the store data available within the app, and wouldn't need to load it before the window is created since it would already exist on startup.

Comment: Existdissolve, thank you for your help. I put my solution here.